# Add new list into listView

Tags: android, mysql, listview, android-listview

There has a `listView` and a add `button` in **Activity A**. The `listView` data is retrieved from `MySQL`.

[![https://i.stack.imgur.com/wVmSK.png][1]][1]

When list is clicked, it will pass the data to **Activity B**, if add `button` is clicked, it will go to **Activity B** for user to add data.  I use `mClickedPosition` to differentiate whether is `list` clicked or `button` clicked.

**Activity A**

```
   ListView listViewUpdate;
    ListAdapter adapter;
    Button add;
    String ID, iD;
    public static final int PROJECT_REQUEST_CODE = 1;
    public static final int CAMERA_REQUEST_CODE = 2;
    int mClickedPosition;
    String ReceiveProject, ReceiveDescription, ReceiveTimeIn, ReceiveTimeOut;
    Integer ReceiveProgress;
    ArrayList<DetailsBean> results = new ArrayList<DetailsBean>();
    String myJSON;
    JSONArray details = null;
    ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>> EditDetails;

     listViewUpdate.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> listView, View view,
                                        int position, long id) {
                    mClickedPosition = position; // listView click
                    HashMap<String, String> clickedItem = EditDetails.get(position);
                    iD = clickedItem.get(Configs.TAG_ID);
                    Intent intent = new Intent(getActivity(), Edit_Details.class);
                    intent.putExtra("iD", iD);
                    intent.putExtra("ID", ID);
                    intent.putExtra("mClickedPosition",mClickedPosition);
                    //Toast.makeText(getActivity(),"This is"+iD+ID,Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                    startActivityForResult(intent, PROJECT_REQUEST_CODE);

                }
            });


          add.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
              @Override
              public void onClick(View v) {
                  mClickedPosition = -1;    // if button clicked
                  Intent intent = new Intent(getActivity(), Edit_Details.class);
                  intent.putExtra("ID", ID);
                  startActivity(intent);
              }

          });
```

Assume user click add `button`.(mClickedposition==-1)

**Activity B**

When save `button` is clicked, data will get inserted into `MySQL` since **mClickedPosition==-1** After that, I want the new data return to Activity A and adding a new list in A, which mean the Activity A should have 2 list now. How can I achieve this ?

```
 save.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {     // if save button clicked
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                Intent returnIntent = new Intent();
                project1 = Project2.getSelectedItem().toString();
                description = Description.getText().toString();
                progress = seekBar.getProgress();
                timeIn = TimeIn.getText().toString();
                timeOut = TimeOut.getText().toString();
                if(mClickedPosition==-1)
                {
                    Add(project1,description,progress,timeIn,timeOut);
                }
                else
                {
                    Update(project1, description, progress, timeIn, timeOut);
                }
                returnIntent.putExtra("project1", project1);
                returnIntent.putExtra("description", description);
                returnIntent.putExtra("progress", progress);
                returnIntent.putExtra("timeIn", timeIn);
                returnIntent.putExtra("timeOut", timeOut);
                setResult(Activity.RESULT_OK, returnIntent);
                finish();

            }
        });
```

**Activity A onActivityResult**

```
  @Override
    public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) { // receive from Activity B and populate ListView A
        if (resultCode == Activity.RESULT_OK) {
            if (requestCode == PROJECT_REQUEST_CODE) {
                ReceiveProject = data.getStringExtra("project1");
                ReceiveDescription = data.getStringExtra("description");
                ReceiveProgress = data.getIntExtra("progress", 0);
                ReceiveTimeIn = data.getStringExtra("timeIn");
                ReceiveTimeOut = data.getStringExtra("timeOut");


                Toast.makeText(getActivity(),ReceiveProject+ReceiveDescription+ReceiveProgress+ReceiveTimeIn+ReceiveTimeOut,Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                if(mClickedPosition==-1)
                { // add list
                    HashMap<String, String> clickedItem = new HashMap<>();
                    clickedItem.put(Configs.TAG_PROJECT, ReceiveProject);
                    clickedItem.put(Configs.TAG_WORKDESCRIPTION, ReceiveDescription);
                    clickedItem.put(Configs.TAG_PERCENTAGE, ReceiveProgress + "");
                    clickedItem.put(Configs.TAG_IN, ReceiveTimeIn);
                    clickedItem.put(Configs.TAG_OUT, ReceiveTimeOut);
                    EditDetails.add(clickedItem);
                    ((BaseAdapter) adapter).notifyDataSetChanged();

                }
                else
                {  // update list
                    HashMap<String, String> clickedItem =EditDetails.get(mClickedPosition);
                    clickedItem.put(Configs.TAG_PROJECT, ReceiveProject);
                    clickedItem.put(Configs.TAG_WORKDESCRIPTION, ReceiveDescription);
                    clickedItem.put(Configs.TAG_PERCENTAGE, ReceiveProgress + "");
                    clickedItem.put(Configs.TAG_IN, ReceiveTimeIn);
                    clickedItem.put(Configs.TAG_OUT, ReceiveTimeOut);
                    ((BaseAdapter) adapter).notifyDataSetChanged();
                }
                //((BaseAdapter) adapter).notifyDataSetChanged();
            }
            }
    }
    }
```

> Now I can see a new list added in Activity A. But when I click the new
>   list and go to Activity B, no data are passed. But if I click the old
>   list, I can see data passed...

Comment: why you are using two adapters?
 ListAdapter adapter;
    CustomBaseAdapter obj;?

Comment: Which adapter you are setting to the ListView?

Comment: @SanjeetAjnabee I have removed the CustomBaseAdapter

Comment: You should make an object class to contain all your data, then make an adapter for that. `ArrayAdapter` is preffered over `BaseAdapter` unless you need special functionality.

Comment: @cricket_007 ArrayList<DetailsBean> results = new ArrayList<DetailsBean>(); ?

Comment: Sure. Where is `ArrayAdapter<DetailsBean> adapter = new ArrayAdapter(..., results);`? Or `DetailBean bean = new DetailBean(...);` and `results.add(bean);`?

Comment: @cricket_007 bro please help..I get stuck :( http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34774015/send-image-from-android-to-mysql-server

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need add or update the new data in the List and then call `notifiDataSetChanged()`;
Change the code in the onActivity result method of your activity A as below-

```
                HashMap<String, String> item =        new HashMap<>();
                item.put(Configs.TAG_PROJECT, ReceiveProject);
                item.put(Configs.TAG_WORKDESCRIPTION, ReceiveDescription);
                item.put(Configs.TAG_PERCENTAGE, ReceiveProgress + "");
                item.put(Configs.TAG_IN, ReceiveTimeIn);
                item.put(Configs.TAG_OUT, ReceiveTimeOut);

                if(mClickedPosition==-1)
                { // add list
                    EditDetails.add(item);

                }
                else
                {  // update list
                    EditDetails.remove(mClickedPosition);
                    mEventsList.add(mClickedPosition,item)
                }
                ((BaseAdapter) adapter).notifyDataSetChanged();
```

Comment: `HashMap<String, String> item =        new HashMap<>();` put after  `ReceiveTimeOut = data.getStringExtra("timeOut");` ?

Comment: Yes , You need these values before adding it to the list na.

Comment: `EditDetails.remove(mClickedPosition);` and 
                    `mEventsList.add(mClickedPosition,item)` for ?

Comment: You need to update the value in the list, I am not sure if updating the HasMaps instance on the particular position and calling the notifyDataSetChanged() works properly.

Comment: Use the way I suggested bro! or move the operation in else and if block.