# send Image from android to MySQL server

Tags: php, android, json, image, uri

[image]

In Activity A, it has 3 `listView`. When submit button is clicked, I want to store the text and imagePath into MySQL and the image stored in PhotoUpload folder.

```
String imagess;
Uri imgURI;

 public void uploadImageAndText(ArrayList<ImageAndText> listItems, final String id) {
            JSONArray jsonArray = new JSONArray();
            try {
                for (ImageAndText i : listItems) {
                    JSONObject object = new JSONObject();
                    String type = i.getType();
                    String[] Type = type.split(":");
                    object.put("type", Type[1]);
                    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), Type[1], Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                    String amount = i.getAmount();
                    String[] Amount = amount.split(":");
                    object.put("amount", Amount[1]);
                    String description = i.getDescription();
                    String[] Description = description.split(":");
                    object.put("description", Description[1]);
                    Uri uploadImage = i.getImage(); //not sure
                    object.put("image", uploadImage); // not sure 
                    object.put("ts_id", id);
                    jsonArray.put(object);
                }
            } catch (JSONException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }

            AddStaff ru = new AddStaff(jsonArray);
            ru.execute();

        }

        class AddStaff extends AsyncTask<String, Void, String> {
            ProgressDialog loading;

            JSONArray jsonArray;

            AddStaff(JSONArray jsonArray) {
                this.jsonArray = jsonArray;
            }

            @Override
            protected void onPreExecute() {
                super.onPreExecute();
                loading = ProgressDialog.show(AddClaims.this, "Please Wait", null, true, true);
            }

            @Override
            protected String doInBackground(String... params) {
                HashMap<String, String> data = new HashMap<String, String>();
                data.put("listItems", jsonArray.toString());
                data.put(Configs.KEY_IMAGE,imagess);  // not sure
                RequestHandler rh = new RequestHandler();
                String result = rh.sendPostRequest(Configs.STAFF_BENEFIT, data);
                return result;
            }

            @Override
            protected void onPostExecute(String s) {
                super.onPostExecute(s);
                loading.dismiss();
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), s, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            }
        }


    }
```

**staffBenefit.php**

```
  <?php
        if( $_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD']=='POST' ){

            if( !empty( $_POST['listItems'] ) ){

                $mysqli = new mysqli("127.0.0.1:3307", "root", "", "androiddb");
                if( $mysqli->connect_errno ) echo "Failed to connect to MySQL";

                $image = $_POST['image'];

                $listItems = json_decode( $_POST['listItems'], true ); 

                $sql="SELECT id FROM staff_benefit ORDER BY id ASC";

                $id=0;

                $res=$mysqli->query( $sql );
                while( $rs=$res->fetch_object() ) $id=$rs->id;

                $path="$id.png";
                $actualpath="http://192.168.107.115:80/Android/CRUD/PhotoUpload/$path";

                $sql="INSERT INTO `staff_benefit` ( `type`, `amount`, `description`, `image`, `ts_id` ) VALUES ( ?, ?, ?, ?, ? )";
                $stmt=$mysqli->prepare( $sql );

                $pathelements=array( realpath( $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'] ), 'CRUD', 'PhotoUpload', '' );
                $savepath = realpath( implode( DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR, $pathelements ) ) . "{$id}.png";

                $bytes=file_put_contents( $savepath, base64_decode( $image ) );
                if( !$bytes ){
                    echo 'Error saving image';  
                }

                if ( $stmt ) {
                     foreach( $listItems as $item ){ 

                        $stmt->bind_param('sssss', $item['type'], $item['amount'], $item['description'], $actualpath, $item['ts_id'] );
                        $res=$stmt->execute();

                        if( !$res ) echo 'Query failed with code: '.$stmt->errno;
                    } 
                }
                $mysqli->close();
            }
        }
    ?>
```

My app doesn't crashed, but I saw this in logCat.

```
01-14 02:05:11.978  20483-21081/com.example.project.myapplication W/System.err﹕ java.lang.NullPointerException
01-14 02:05:11.978  20483-21081/com.example.project.myapplication W/System.err﹕ at libcore.net.UriCodec.encode(UriCodec.java:132)
01-14 02:05:11.978  20483-21081/com.example.project.myapplication W/System.err﹕ at java.net.URLEncoder.encode(URLEncoder.java:57)
01-14 02:05:11.978  20483-21081/com.example.project.myapplication W/System.err﹕ at com.example.project.myapplication.Handler.RequestHandler.getPostDataString(RequestHandler.java:118)
01-14 02:05:11.978  20483-21081/com.example.project.myapplication W/System.err﹕ at com.example.project.myapplication.Handler.RequestHandler.sendPostRequest(RequestHandler.java:51)
01-14 02:05:11.978  20483-21081/com.example.project.myapplication W/System.err﹕ at com.example.project.myapplication.GUI.AddClaims$AddInfo$AddStaff.doInBackground(AddClaims.java:480)
01-14 02:05:11.978  20483-21081/com.example.project.myapplication W/System.err﹕ at com.example.project.myapplication.GUI.AddClaims$AddInfo$AddStaff.doInBackground(AddClaims.java:459)
```

Can someone please assist me how to achieve this ? How to store the URI image into folder ? Thanks.

**Edited**

```
 @Override
            protected String doInBackground(String... params) {

                for (int index = 0; index < jsonArray.length(); index++) {
                    try {
                        JSONObject jsonObject = jsonArray.getJSONObject(index);
                        String strUri = jsonObject.getString("image");
                        HashMap<String, String> data = new HashMap<String, String>();
                        data.put("listItems", jsonArray.toString());
                        data.put(Configs.KEY_IMAGE, getStringImage(Uri.parse(strUri)));
                        RequestHandler rh = new RequestHandler();
                        String result = rh.sendPostRequest(Configs.STAFF_BENEFIT, data);
                        return result;
                    } catch (Exception e) {
                    }
                }
                return "";
            }

            @Override
            protected void onPostExecute(String s) {
                super.onPostExecute(s);
                loading.dismiss();
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), s, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            }
        }


        public String getStringImage(Uri imgUri) {
            try {
                Bitmap bitmap = MediaStore.Images.Media.getBitmap(getContentResolver(), imgUri);
                ByteArrayOutputStream baos = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
                bitmap.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.JPEG, 100, baos);
                byte[] imageBytes = baos.toByteArray();
                String encodedImage = Base64.encodeToString(imageBytes, Base64.DEFAULT);
                return encodedImage;
            } catch (Exception e) {
            }

            return "";
        }
    }
```

When I check MySQL, three data get inserted but the path stored in column image is the same (the last one) and only the last image stored inside the photoUpload folder.

[image]

It suppose to have 36.png,37.png and 38.png, but it saved 36.png only

Comment: Use `object.put("image", uploadImage.toString());` instead of `object.put("image", uploadImage);`

Comment: @ρяσѕρєяK what should I change for the `imagess` ?

Comment: @cricket_007 I read the post many times but still cannot figuring out my problem

Comment: @Tony: See my answer probably help

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> send Image from android to MySQL server

Getting `NPE` because `imagess` Array is `null`.

Because want to send multiple images from device to server. iterate over JSONArray which sending in `doInBackground` and get `Bitmap` from Uri before sending to server:

**1.** In `uploadImageAndText` method store Uri as String in JSONObject.Change:

```
object.put("image", uploadImage);
```

to

```
object.put("image", uploadImage.toString());
```

**2.** Create a method for getting Bitmap using Uri and encoded image String like:

```
public String getStringImage(Uri imgUri){
    Bitmap bitmap = MediaStore.Images.Media.getBitmap(getContentResolver(),imgUri);
    ByteArrayOutputStream baos = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
    bitmap.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.JPEG, 100, baos);
    byte[] imageBytes = baos.toByteArray();
    String encodedImage = Base64.encodeToString(imageBytes, Base64.DEFAULT);
    return encodedImage;
}
```

**3.** Finally call `getStringImage` in `doInBackground` :

```
@Override
protected String doInBackground(String... params) {

  for(int index=0;index<jsonArray.length();index++){
   JSONObject jsonObject=jsonArray.getJSONObject(index);
    String strUri=jsonObject.getString("image");
    HashMap<String, String> data = new HashMap<String, String>();
    data.put("listItems", jsonArray.toString());
    data.put(Configs.KEY_IMAGE,getStringImage(Uri.parse(strUri)));  
    RequestHandler rh = new RequestHandler();
    String result = rh.sendPostRequest(Configs.STAFF_BENEFIT, data);
  }
   return "";        
 }
```

Comment: @Tony: means ? not getting u of course you need to add try-catch. we are not here to provide to compiled code hint is sufficient

Comment: @Tony: If u have any doubt the see https://www.simplifiedcoding.net/android-upload-image-to-server-using-php-mysql/ tutorial for PHP related issue

Comment: @ρяσѕρєяK ya, I follow his tutorial but my image size too large and cannot be retrieved out. So I change to this method. Will this method consider as efficiency? Hopefully it works

Comment: @Tony: Post it as new question with PHP tags to get feedback from PHP developers.Thanks

Comment: @ρяσѕρєяK sir your code works as I can see there are image and text inserted into MySQL. But the problem is it only save the last image into mysql. I check the MySQL db, three data get inserted, but the image is the third one

Comment: @Tony check size of jsonArray?

Comment: @ρяσѕρєяK sir check my edited post again, see whether i'm writing it correctly or not

Comment: @Tony: here `$path="$id.png";` using same name for all images so last image is available `$path=".time().$id.png";` then check working or not

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/100627/discussion-between-tony-and--k).

Comment: It still insert one image only but all the text can be inserted

Comment: need to put the actual part in while loop isin't ?

Comment: @Tony: in which while loop?